# What's the difference between gllight and glulookat (depending the order)

Tags: opengl

I would like to know what is the difference between:

```
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
gluLookAt(...)
```

and

```
gluLookAt(...)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
```

Because for me, it looks pretty the same (unless the order of instructions)

Comment: "*unless the order of instructions*" I'm not quite sure what you mean. The order you do things in can *matter*. For example, if you have two variables A and B, `(B*A) + B` is different from `B * (A+B)`. Are you asking if the order of operations actually does matter in this case or what?

Comment: well i'm asking, what's the difference between these two pieces of code :) 
I know there is a difference, just i don't know what's the difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lThe light position vector will by transformed using the current `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix at the time of the `glLighttv()` call to get the eye-space position of the light source, which is used for the lighting calculations when rendering the primitives. So the order of these operations does matter.

YOur code snippets are very small. Let's assume the current modelview matrix is just identity. In this case, the first varian would lead to the light position being directly set in eye-space. So the light source actually moves when the camera moves, the relative position of the light and the camera always stays the same.

The latter variant would set the light position according to the current view matrix set by `gluLookAt()`. If you move the camera, the relative positions of light and camera would change, the resulting effect would be that the light has a stable world space position, e.g. you could actually move near the light source.

Comment: So the second piece of code is like the sun in our real world ? I mean we can move  but the light stays at the same place ?

Comment: @Damiii: That is not the imporant difference here. The sun is usually approximated by a directional light, that is a ligt source which is infinitely far awy, so all of the rays are parallel. You of course would still want to use the latter version for that, but also for small locol point lights, light a light bulb in a room. The first variant would be something like a headlight.